# How do I toggle twitter bootstrap as validation in web form?

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I know I can place any value from my code behind virtually anywhere on my aspx by using:

```
<%=myString%>
```

I also know that in order for me to make a field required using twitter bootstrap I need to use `required` before my tag closes as in:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" CssClass="standard_tb" required/>
```

In my project I want to be able to set that variable to `required` or <kbd>null</kbd>.

When I try using the method above I get the **The server tag is not well formed** if i use `<%#myString%>` within my label or I get the error **Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs** if I use `<%=myString%>`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen you cannot add `<% %>` tags to a .NET server control.

What you need to do is in the code behind set:

```
if (someCondition)
    txtFName.Attributes.Add("required", null);
else
    txtFName.Attributes.Remove("required");
```

If you need XHTML compliance then instead you'd use the line:

```
txtFName.Attributes.Add("required", "required");
```

Which would render as:

```
<input id="txtFName" class="standard_tb" required="required" />
```